# Adding components within a snakes and ladders game

Tags: python

```
def placecheck():
    global boardplace
    global playerturn
    ladders = [3, 6, 20, 36, 68, 63]
    ladderadd = [48, 21, 40, 19, 32, 30]
    snakes = [25, 34, 47, 65, 87, 91, 99]
    snakesub = [20, 33, 28, 13, 30, 30, 30]
    for i in range(0,5):
        if boardplace[playerturn] == ladders[i]:
            boardplace[playerturn] + ladderadd[i]

    for i in range(0, 5):
        if boardplace[playerturn] == snakes[i]:
            boardplace[playerturn] - snakesub[i]
    print("Player " + str(playerturn) + " is on square " + str(boardplace[playerturn]) + " of 100!!!\n")
    roll()
```

I cannot get the boardplace [playerturn] to add.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Showing us your code is not enough for us to know what your question is. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a `+=` (and `-=` later on), i.e.

```
...
    for i in range(0,5):
        if boardplace[playerturn] == ladders[i]:
            boardplace[playerturn] += ladderadd[i]


    for i in range(0, 5):
        if boardplace[playerturn] == snakes[i]:
            boardplace[playerturn] -= snakesub[i]
...
```